# How do I make an excel formula skip empty cells

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with data in a single row.  The data is arranged by year with the earliest date in the right most cell and the latest date in the far left cell.

What I need is a formula that will begin looking at the cells beginning on the right (earlier date) and move to the left toward a later date skipping the empty cells.  As soon as it finds data in one of the cells I need it to stop and show the value in that cell.

I have attached a picture as an example, in that picture I need it to begin at the cell for 2003 and begin moving left ignoring empty cells until it finds a cell with data.  In this case the cell for 2005 contains data.  I need it to copy that value ($2.43) and place it in the cell marked earliest value.

In the pictue I manually entered 2.43 in the cell for 2005 to show what i need.!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LOOKUP` function to get the last value in a row, so if you have years in `A1:J1` and dollar amounts in `A2:J2` just use this formula to get the last numeric value from `A2:J2`

`=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A2:J2)`

9.99E+307 is [almost] the largest value that Excel allows, when you use that "big num" as lookup value the result is the **last** number in the range

Answer (score 0):

I made two ranges, starting E4 to J4, I place 1,2,3,4,5,6. Below (thus range: E5-J5) I placed 6,5,4,3,2,1.

In a random cell I placed this formula:

```
=INDEX(E5:J5,MATCH(MIN(E4:J4),E4:J4,0))
```

This look in E4:J4 for the number that matched MIN(E4:J4), thus the lowest number. Then selects that value, matching the index, in the range E5:J5.

Answer (score 0):

As follows from your image - **year should be less than 10 yr history**. In that case try following formula (I suppose that your data ( years and values) are in `B3:X4` range):

```
=HLOOKUP(MIN(IF((B4:X4<>"")*(B3:X3>YEAR(NOW())-10),B3:X3)),B3:X4,2,0)
```

Note, that it is an array formula, so you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

---

If you don't need to use condition *year should be less than 10 yr history*, just remove `*(B3:X3>YEAR(NOW())-10)` from the formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(MIN(IF(B4:X4<>"",B3:X3)),B3:X4,2,0)
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.